# Does Varnish have something similar to Redis LRU?

Tags: varnish

If my server memory is full I like to clean old objects by the number of times people call them.
Can I do that in Varnish?

Answer (score 1):

Varnish storages (i.e. malloc or file) implement a LRU strategy when objects need to be removed (i.e. nuked) from the cache. From the docs [1]:

> Watch the `n_lru_nuked` counter with `varnishstat` or some other tool. If
>   you have a lot of LRU activity then your cache is evicting objects due
>   to space constraints and you should consider increasing the size of
>   the cache.

[1] https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.3/users-guide/sizing-your-cache.html